# Objective-C GUI: nonblocking interface?

Tags: objective-c, user-interface

I have an audio renderer which does some elaborate processing of a sound signal and then plays it back in real-time. I want to make a GUI that allows to modify some parameters (e.g. volume and stuff like that). Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I necessarily need to multithread it?

Thanks!